# Delegate some admin roles, but not all?

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2003, administrator, active-directory

A client has asked for a group of secondary AD admins, who is supposed to be able to help users do program updates, configure printers etc. The client really want to prevent this group of secondary admins from, for example, be able to read the content of a clients full disk. Is it possible to somehow delegate a subset of admin rights, to be able to update / install etc, but not per default giving full access to everything?

AD is Server 2003, all clients are windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as setting file permissions for the relevant groups (either on the local machine or ideally via group policy at Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > File System) it is also possible to grant specific "privileges" to groups. The Microsoft documentation is available here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd277404.aspx

In brief, you need to create or edit a GPO and in the Group Policy console, go to Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > User Rights Assignment.

Some of the policy names may require a little bit of interpretation (to say the least). The "Load and Unload Device Drivers" right for example controls the ability to install printers.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you roll out your implementation across the workstations on your network you can create a user group that is considered admin then restrict access rights on a case-by-case basis.

So if you use a system like Symantec's Ghost to setup all your workstations, then just go through the permissions dialogue (right click folder>properties>security tab) to set what areas you want the user to NOT have access to. Just make sure when doing this that it executes recursively into all the sub folders.

Whatever rights you want to remove will have to be done on a case by case basis, either through registry manipulation or removing the simpler ones through Windows' security/permissions dialogue.